# Unresolved function or method mongoose.connect() WebStorm

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, webstorm

I'm configuring the **server.js** file in my Node.js application. I've added **mongoose** to the list of dependencies in **package.json** file. Then, I require this package at the top of the file and try to connect to MongoDB Atlas.

The ***Unresolved function or method connect()***  warning is displayed on the *mongoose.connect()* method.

What can be wrong?

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv').config();

/* App Configuration */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});

/* MongoDB Connection */
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true});

/* Listener Configuration */
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log("The app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.1"
  },
...
```

.env:

```
PORT=3000
MONGO_URI= *my mongodb uri*
```

[image]

Comment: Is it just the Webstorm giving the warning or are you facing problems running the code via command line as well?
If code is running fine via command line then probably some issue with Webstorm itself

Comment: @Kartoos I used Replit as well, everything works fine there. Will try to create this project in another editor.

Answer (score 3):

So, I run the application, test it, all the records are being saved to the MongoDB collection properly. I can assume, that it's an issue of WebStorm itself.

Comment: Try this first (if you have not done it yet): "Go to package.json, press Alt+Enter on 'mongoose' -> "Instal @types/mongoose""

Comment: If still nothing -- check if this is your case: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7416893597586-there-is-a-problem-with-mongoose